# Can't make PHP function work inside HTML inside PHP

Tags: php, html, image

I wrote this code, it gets an image from a link that varies according to where you are:

```
<img src='http://chusmix.com/Imagenes/grupos/<?php echo substr(get_search_query(), 1); ?>.jpg'>
```

I want to make that code run if a PHP condition proves true, but I cannot make it work. It seems that the function doesn't return a value instead it takes the link textually. I mean it goes to http://chusmix.com/Imagenes/grupos/.jpg literally. However the code works correctly by itself.

This is the PHP code:

```
<?php
    $search=get_search_query();
    $first=$search[0];

    if ($first=="#"){
          echo "<html>";
          echo "<img src='http://chusmix.com/Imagenes/grupos/<?php echo substr(get_search_query(), 1); ?>.jpg'>";
    }
    ?>
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You are already inside the php tag. So there is no need for `<?php` and `?>`.

Try:

```
echo "<img src='http://chusmix.com/Imagenes/grupos/".substr($search,1).".jpg'>";
```

Answer (score 0):

Replace line

```
echo "<img src='http://chusmix.com/Imagenes/grupos/<?php echo substr(get_search_query(), 1); ?>.jpg'>";
```

with

```
echo "<img src='http://chusmix.com/Imagenes/grupos/" . substr(get_search_query(), 1) . ".jpg'>";
```